# Selective focus optical illusion

Tags: focus, depth-of-field, tilt-shift, selective-focus

I have come across some shots from other people and they create something like an illusion to me and trick me of the scale of the actual scenery.

For example, this shot by [@chuttersnap](https://unsplash.com/@chuttersnap) on Unsplash made me think that this it is miniature; some sort of Meccano, plastic model or a 3D recreation. It looks too perfect and clean!
[image: selective focus photo of orange and white bus surrounded with trees photo]

Proof that it is actually real can be seen when you zoom-in and notice there's a person near the front of the bus, some too fine detail on the roof of the bus stop and some other details.

I have tried to capture pictures in a similar style using a DJI Mavic Pro Platinum drone, tried editing with Photoshop, but I can't give my shots that feeling.

What do you think the camera configuration and settings are? Is this effect entirely made with graphic manipulation? Any hint or advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilt-Shift lenses can isolate the plane of focus to achieve this look. 
[image]

Many of today's cameras have built-in software to create the same isolated focus.
Your camera may already have this feature. Look in the manual for "miniature effect".

Here is a page from a Canon S110 camera manual:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a tilt effect. Specialized lenses are made so that the focal plane no longer is parallel to your sensor/film.